# TestNG @Test method running at feature level, how to run at scenario level

Tags: selenium, automation, cucumber, testng, testng-dataprovider

I want to execute @AfterMethod at scenario level(Just after each Scenario) of the feature file. But @AfterMethod executing at feature level(after all scenarios) of the feature file.
how can I achieve this.
Below is the my code snippet.

1. Runner Class.

   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   @CucumberOptions(features = "Features", glue = { "com.dell.clouddam.stepdefinitions" },
   dryRun = false,
   plugin = {
   "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html", "pretty",
   "json:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.json" }, monochrome = true)
   public class MyTestRunner {

   ```
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    private DriverFactory driverFactory;    
    private WebDriver driver;   //these are made private because these are specific to this class only.
    private ConfigReader configReader;
    Properties properties;


    @BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public void getProperty() {
        configReader = new ConfigReader();
        properties = configReader.initProp();
        System.out.println("@BeforeClass getpropeety ");

    }

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void launchBrowser() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception {
        String browserName = properties.getProperty("environment");
        driver = driverFactory.initDriver(browserName); 
        driver.get(properties.getProperty("author_url"));
        ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }



    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] features() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures();
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature", dataProvider = "features")
    public void feature(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature.getCucumberFeature());
    }

    @AfterMethod(description = "Executes After Each Iteration")
    public void afterMethod(ITestResult res) throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public void afterTest() throws Throwable {

    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() throws Throwable {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }
   ```

   }
2. DriverFactory.java

   public class DriverFactory {

   public static WebDriver driver;
   HashMap<String, Object> moonConfig = new HashMap<String, Object>();

   private ConfigReader configReader=new ConfigReader();;
   Properties properties = configReader.initProp();

   public WebDriver initDriver(String environment) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception {
   System.out.println("Browser value is - " + environment);

   ```
    if (environment.equals("chrome")) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    else if (environment.equals("firefox")) {
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    else if (environment.equals("safari")) {
        driver = new SafariDriver();
    } 
    else {
        System.out.println("Please select the correct browser value");
    }
    getDriver().manage().deleteAllCookies();
    getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
    return getDriver();
   ```

   }

   public static synchronized WebDriver getDriver() {
   return driver;
   }
   }
3. Pom.xml

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleDAM</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paulhammant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ngwebdriver</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.48.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.jesg/phantomjsdriver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jesg</groupId>
            <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.saucelabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>sauce_bindings</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.26-incubating</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>CloudDAM.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

For cucumber, you would need to use Cucumber-jvm's annotations eg. (io.cucumber.java.After) @After, @Before - run before and after each scenario.  There is no annotation which supports feature end. There is @AfterAll - which runs after all features all scenarios. If you want more granular control, you need to implement ConcurrentEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tags on feature level and scenario level and you can set value and priority in each hook.

```
@Before(value="@smoke", order=1)
public void browserSetup() {
    System.out.println("I am inside browserSetup");
}
```

And you can define the tags in the TestRunner

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/featuresWithTags/Tags.feature",
    glue = {"stepDefinitions"},
    monochrome = true,
    tags = "@Smoke or @Regression and @Important")
```

Comment: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#hooks